# Is there a way of finding out what reboot flag is causing a pending reboot

Tags: windows-server

Sounds daft, and may not be loaded the way I want it to go so background

Patching servers and reboots

We patch every month but after constant reboots we notice there are reboot flags still pending, what's causing these is it MS stack or other ie AV etc

I know the locations of the reboot flags but ideally want to know what is causing the pending reboot and stop me going around in a circle and if need be point to other teams who install software and not rebooting etc

So if anyone has any ideas or views and thoughts it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which reboot flags ? What is "patching" ?

Comment: windows server patching, so after monthly / roll updates we reboot the servers multiple times via big fix but reboot flags show, so when investigating the server it shows reboot required but if we reboot again multiple times the flag still doesnt clear so would like to know whats being flagged for reboot.

Comment: Which version of Windows? Does Windows Update show any information? Check also "View update history".

Comment: seems to be versions 2k8 through to 2019 which is the confusing part we thought it may be a false flag as it is effecting roughly 685 servers at present (out of 5k plus)

Comment: We need some more information than that. It's probably Windows Update that signals it, but for so many versions there might be multiple reasons, even just the antivirus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you mean
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager

PendingFileRenameOperations

Comment: thank you very much